# View "$LDAPRDNHier" not updating after adding/editing documents

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, ibm-domino

We have an IBM Domino server running LDAP with an extended user directory. This has worked fine for years but we have suddenly run into an issue with the LDAP failing to find users that are newly added or edited.

Debugging the LDAP service has shown that it looks for users in the "$LDAPRDNHier" view, and we have seen that it works correctly after running a

```
load updall -R -T $LDAPRDNHier path/to/extendednames.nsf
```

The view is set to:

1. Index refresh: "Auto, after first use" (we also tried "Automatic")
2. Fully indexed (was not indexed but we turned it on while debugging)
3. The view selection formula does not contain any date specific conditions (this is apparently a cause to this problem)

But we are still having problems.

So far, the only solution we have that updates the view is either:

1. Manually opening the view in Notes and refreshing it
2. Running the updall rebuild command specified above

Neither of these solutions are good enough as we need this view to be updated on document change (as it was working previously). No change has been made to this view that caused this to fail.

Any help is greatly appreciated.